# ExtJS 4 Drawing and Charting Example is Not Drawing

Tags: extjs, drawing, extjs4

This is driving me crazy and I've tried a number of different options. I'm going through all the materials [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/drawing_and_charting), trying to cram as much ExtJS 4 into my brain as possible for a project. In the Drawing and Charting section there are two examples. Below, the first example draws a yellow circle, the second example draws no circle. Why?

First example (draws a yellow circle):

```
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function(){
    var drawComponent = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
        viewBox: false,
        items: [{
            type: 'circle',
            fill: '#ffc',
            radius: 100,
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        width: 230,
        height: 230,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [drawComponent]
    }).show();
}
});
```

Second example (draws no circle):

```
Ext.application({
name: 'HelloExt',
launch: function(){
    // Create a draw component
    var drawComponent = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
        viewBox: false
    });

    // Create a window to place the draw component in
    Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        width: 220,
        height: 230,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [drawComponent]
    }).show();

    // Add a circle sprite
    var myCircle = drawComponent.surface.add({
        type: 'circle',
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: 100,
        fill: '#cc5'
    });
}
});
```

I've tried innumerable ways of adding the Sprite to the drawComponent and the only that works is if I give it as a declared member of items in the drawComponent instantiation. I'm getting no errors in the Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix involves adding `.show(true)` to the end of the sprite statement. Like this:

```
var myCircle = drawComponent.surface.add({
    type: 'circle',
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 100,
    fill: '#cc5'
}).show(true);
```

I really wish this had been in the ExtJS 4 documentation.